# broadcast rerciver for volume focus

Tags: java, android, volume

My app needs to check weather the volume focus is on the media volume (which means that if you press the volume increasment or deacresment buttons on the phone' it will control the media volume). Is this even beeing broadcasted?

Answer (score 0):

Try with AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html

```
onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
      *
     //Check if the audio focus is on the media volume
     *
     Intent service = new Intent(Yourservice.this, Service2.class);
     startService(service);
```

}

Comment: this gets the volume of the media volume, I want to check weather the focus is on media volume, and if it is, I want it to be broadcasted so it can run a service

Comment: I think that OnAudioChangeListener does the job

Comment: but would it work like a broadcast? if the application isn't currently running, and the focus would cange to the media volume, would it let the application know?

Comment: That works only if the app is open, I want the service to run even if the app was never open

Comment: but once app has been opened, the service continue running in background when you change to another app? If this is your case you can run the service on BOOT_COMPLETED. This means that start to run when you turn on the device. There are many tutorials on this site.